# Is there any Agents of SHIELD and Thor: The Dark World crossover?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield, thor-the-dark-world, crossovers

I'm watching Agents of SHIELD at the moment, and I am wondering if there is any cross over between it and Thor: The Dark World. Is there a particular episode that ties in to the film or any spoilers which would result from watching out of order?

Comment: Not specifically Thor Dark World but Lady Sif does show up in one or two S.H.I.E.L.D episodes.

Answer (score 13):

**Yes.**

In a [press release published two days ago](http://marvel.com/news/story/21453/declassifying_marvels_agents_of_shield_the_well), Marvel gave some background for “The Well”, which broadcasts on 19th November:

> After Marvel’s *Thor: The Dark World* hits theatres<sup>1</sup> November 8, *Marvel’s Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* will feel the repercussions November 19 with an all-new episode!

The official synopsis is:

> In the aftermath of the events chronicled in the feature film Marvel’s *Thor: The Dark World*, Coulson and the Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. pick up the pieces—one of which threatens to destroy a member of the team.

The guest cast (in the press release) doesn’t list any of the major actors or actresses from *Thor*, so it seems any crossover will only be in events, not in characters.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> This is the US release date; it was released internationally on 30th October.</sup>

Comment: For UK readers: this episode will be broadcast on Channel 4 on 22nd Nov. When, ironically, I'll be in the States. Source: [https://twitter.com/MarvelUK/status/398068639472943105](https://twitter.com/MarvelUK/status/398068639472943105)

Comment: This episode has an Asgardian plot in which Thor was mentioned several times. No guest appearances from actors in the Thor movie.

Answer (score 5):

**Given that Thor: The Dark World releases November 8, 2013 (in the USA). If they were going to film a crossover event, they would have to be filming it right now.**

S01-E04, The Asset, and S01-E05, Girl in the Flower Dress are already in the can. I think it would be difficult to put out something that could cross over in a timely fashion. I also don't think that is the nature of the show based on an interview with executive producer, Joss Whedon.

#### Interview Reference: TVGuide.com

**Joss Whedon said in a recent [interview](http://www.tvguide.com/news/marvel-agents-shield-abc-1068882.aspx) regarding the Dark World:**

> When Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. comes to ABC this fall, fans of The Avengers — and the films that preceded it — will feel right at home. But how much will that world cross over with Marvel's upcoming Phase 2, which includes Captain America: Winter Soldier, Thor: The Dark World and The Avengers movie sequel?
>
> "There will be as much [crossover] as we can allow," executive producer Joss Whedon said at the Television Critics Association fall TV previews on Sunday. "We're still working that out. The important thing is it's a fun opportunity. **It's not the reason for the show. We don't want to be an Easter egg farm. This show has to work for those people who haven't seen those movies and won't be seeing them.**"

(Emphasis mine.)

With that said, it sounds as if you will be able to watch Agents of SHIELD without fear of missing something necessary to watch any of the upcoming movies. Like comics, these two productions appear to be trying to be independent, while sharing mutual elements, in this case, the organization of SHIELD.

Comment: They did incorporate one element form the Phase 2 films in the premiere episode an individual was infected with a modified version of the Extremis package seen in Iron Man III.  I think that was probably the easiest to incorporate post Avengers as IM3 was completed about the same time S.H.I.E.L.D. began production.

Comment: @Monty129 They've referenced the Battle of New York once or twice, too.  The main point is that it's not spoilery and doesn't lock out anyone who doesn't know the reference (Extremis included).